# Querying entity by parameter inside list property

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I am trying to write a query in HQL but it doesn't work. The query filters Students by Grades. Grade is a ManyToMany list inside Student's class.

Exapmle (Student.java):

```
@NamedQuery(name = "getStudentsByGrade" , query = "from Student where :grade in grades")
```

The Student class has list property:

```
Private List<Grade> grades;
```

Comment: What should your query do? Its name implies that it should get a grade based on a student. But the query suggests a completely different thing.

Comment: If the query is what indicates what you want to do, read https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-member-of-collection-predicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `:grade member of grades` was what i looked for.